# Какой результат дает оператор global?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, переменные, книги, функции

Читая книгу Лауры Томсон "Разработка Web-приложений с помощью на PHP и MySQL" натолкнулся на следующие отрывки текста

1. > Переменные, которые объявлены вне функции, действуют в области от оператора, в котором они объявлены до конца файла, но не внутри функций. Эта область называется глобальной областью, а такие переменные — глобальными переменными.
2. > Ключевое слово global может использоваться для указания вручную того, что переменная, которая определена или используется внутри функции, будет иметь
   > глобальную область действия.
3. > Если нужно, чтобы переменная, созданная внутри функции, была глобальной,
   > можно использовать ключевое слово global, как показано в следующем примере:

   ```
   function fn ()
   {
   global $var;
   $var = "contents";
   echo "inside the function, \$var = ".$var."<br>";
   ```

   }

   ```
   fn ( ) ;
   echo "outside the function, \$var = ".$var."<br>";
   ```
4. > В этом примере переменная Svar была явно объявлена как глобальная, т.е. после вызова функции переменная будет существовать и вне функции. Вывод этого сценария будет выглядеть следующим образом:

   ```
   inside the function, $var = contents
   outside the function, $var = contents
   ```

   1. 

> Ключевое слово global можно использовать также в начале сценария при первом
> использовании переменной для объявления того, что весь сценарий должен быть областью ее действия. Вероятно, это — наиболее распространенное использование ключевого слова global.
> Как видно из приведенных примеров, вполне допустимо повторно использовать имя
> переменной внутри и снаружи функции без взаимного влияния между ними. Однако,
> в общем случае делать это не рекомендуется, поскольку, не вникнув в код и не приняв во внимание область действия переменных, пользователи могут решить, что эти
> переменные являются одной и той же переменной.

Объясните пожалуйста разночтения между 1-4 и 5 пунктами (стр. 131-133 вышеуказанной книги).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Переменные, которые объявлены вне функции, действуют в области от оператора, в котором они объявлены до конца файла, но не внутри функций.
>
> весь сценарий должен быть областью ее действия.

Насколько я понял, весь сценарий - это различные файлы, которые выполняются. Но при этом, если мы в функции объявим переменную без **global** она будет локальная для этой функции.

На сколько я знаю, это еще настраивается через php.ini, эти области видимости, к примеру чтобы объявленная переменная была видна на всем сценарии.

Comment: @IVsevolod 5 пункт как я понял прочитав главу книги комментирует кусок кода из пункта 3 (если все таки я не ошибаюсь - 5 пункт приводится в самом конце главы спустя 2-3 абзаца после 3 пункта), но как мне кажется и как показывает результат выполнения кода работа производится с одной и той же переменной за счет использования оператора `global`, поэтому я и задал этот вопрос.

Comment: если писать

    global $b;
    function xx()
    {
       global $b;
    }

то в функции будет та же переменная. Если в функции не написать global то они будут разные.

А при использовании include - global позволяет возможность, чтобы во всех файлах сценария эта переменная виделась.

Comment: http://ideone.com/vsoF73  
Наверно все встанет на свои места в понимании вопроса.

Comment: Спасибо @IVsevolod и @ReinRaus 5 пункт комментировал действительно другой участок кода и из него вытекает следующий вывод, что оператор `global` делает переменную видимой везде при применении его внутри функции, а использование его вне функций не приводит к видимости переменной внутри функций. Отсюда следует также, что использование `global` вне функций бесполезно (см. http://ideone.com/vsoF73 ).